# "XML or text declaration not at start of entity" error in jsp

Tags: xml-parsing

i am trying to make my web application multibrowser compatible. Existing works perfectly in IE. But i am facing below issue when i try to run it in Mozilla firefox.

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: localhost:8080/cdwweb/EC.do?_xsl=pages/ic_module.xsl
Line Number 3, Column 1:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^
```

below is code which i think might be cause of issue because error is thrown from below code file and not the one mentioned in error above.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>

<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");

    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    String xslFileName = (String)request.getAttribute("_xsl");

    xslFileName = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(xslFileName);

%>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="<%=xslFileName %>"?>

<root>

<dummy></dummy>

</root>
```

There are no spaces before or after  tag.

Guys, Appreciating you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any white space before the XML declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So, modify your file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>
...
```

and everything should work properly.

Comment: Hi i have tried that but still getting below error:               Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Comment: @Prashant.patil that's another error, other questions here on SO exist wrt that issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parsing+an+XSLT+stylesheet+failed

Comment: Thanks. But what should i do after this error. What should i try next?

Comment: As I said that second error is *not related* to the error this question was originally about.  First read the answers related to the second error, if your specific issue is not addressed in one of the answers create a new question specifically about that second problem.  That is how Stack Overflow should be used.

Comment: But present code working correctly in IE browser. Its only giving problem when i am using application in Mozilla Browser.

Comment: @Prashant.patil might be that you use some nonstandard feature that doesn't work in IE - but anyways, that should be the subject of a *new question* (after having looked through the related questions I referred to above, and including enough information about *that specific issue*, eg the source of the xslt file)